# Cloud function publishing message to topic is very slow

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Publishing message from my cloud function to pubsub is usually taking around 200/300ms does anyone had success using batching inside cloud function (v1) ? Is there any others recommendations to improve this latency ?

I am bit concern of using batching inside cloud function.

Here is my code:

```java
public String send(final Notification notification) {


    try {

      final TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(this.projectId, this.topicId);
      Publisher publisher = null;

      try {

        publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();

        final PubsubMessage pubsubMessage =
            PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
             .setData(copyFromUtf8(notification.getContent()))
             .putAllAttributes(notification.asMap()).setData(data)
            .build();

        final ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);

        // Add an asynchronous callback to handle publish success / failure.
        ApiFutures.addCallback(
            future,
            new ApiFutureCallback<>() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {}

              @Override
              public void onSuccess(final String messageId) {},

            MoreExecutors.directExecutor());

        return future.get();
      } finally {
        if (publisher != null) {
          publisher.shutdown();
          publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
      }

    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should provide the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the publisher on every message is going to result in slowness as you have to establish the connection every time. You should create the publisher once and share it across calls to `send`.

Comment: Would you usually shutdown the publisher only on app shutdown ?